# Correct Usage of ArgumentException?

Tags: c#, exception

From what I've seen, `ArgumentExceptions` are usually used like such:

```
public void UpdateUser(User user)
{
    if (user == null) throw new ArgumentException("user");
    // etc...
}
```

but what if I have something like this:

```
public void UpdateUser(int idOfUser)
{
    var user = GetUserById(idOfUser);
    if (user == null) throw new ArgumentException("idOfUser");
    // etc...
}
```

Is that still an `ArgumentException`?

Comment: Technically the first should be `ArgumentNullException`...

Comment: For the second one, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21146594/613130) (in comments) they suggest `ObjectNotFoundException`

Comment: @xanatos - those 2 comments make up 1 answer

Comment: If anything, the 2nd example is more of an ArgumentException then the 1st one (which should be ArgumentNullException)

Comment: In your 2nd scenario, I can only think of *one* reason you'd want to throw an `ArgumentException` (or derived) and that is if the method can tell *for sure* that the received `idOfUser` is out of range (negative, zero... depending on your db specs). You'd then want to throw an `ArgumentOutOfRange` exception. Other than that, favor a design that produces a custom operation result object indicating success or failure (and the reason for the latter).

Comment: `ArgumentException` and derived classes are `developer` errors and there should **never** be a reason to handle them at runtime. **DON'T EVER** design an API in a way that forces the using dev to rely on handling an `ArgumentException` to deal with the possibility of missing data. This is *not* what those exception exists for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the name suggests, an `ArgumentException` is an exception about an argument. It means the argument was somehow inherently wrong.

The general form is:

```
public void SomeMethod(SomeType arg)
{
  if(!TestArgValid(arg))
    throw new ArgumentException("arg"); //Or more specific is possible
                                        //e.g. ArgumentNullException
    /* Actually do stuff */
}
```

**If** the **only** possible way that `GetUserById` could fail was that there was something inherently incorrect with the value of `idOfUser` then the following would both be the same in practice:

```
public void UpdateUser(int idOfUser)
{
  if(!TestValid(idOfUser))
    throw new ArgumentException("idOfUser");
  var user = GetUserById(idOfUser);
  // Do stuff with user
}

public void UpdateUser(int idOfUser)
{
  var user = GetUserById(idOfUser);
  if(user == null)
    throw new ArgumentException("idOfUser");
  // Do stuff with user
}
```

And **if** it turned out to be for some reason faster or less wasteful of some resource to test `user` after the fact than `idOfUser` before the fact and **if** there were no side-effects of calling `GetUserById`, and **if** the difference actually mattered then **maybe** the second version would be a reasonable optimisation of the first.

But that only holds if all of the *if*s above hold, and it's then a weird way of detecting an invalid argument that has some specific advantage where we benefit from the encapsulation of methods by hiding that weirdness from everything else.

Chances are there could be a valid `idOfUser` for which there was no corresponding `user`, in which case it certainly wasn't an argument exception.

Comment: Hi Jon. Appreciate this an old one, but is it worth fixing the user of `ArgumentException` in your code snippet? In the constructor shown, the string is used to specify a message, not the name of the argument (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.argumentexception.-ctor?view=net-6.0#System_ArgumentException__ctor_System_String_).

Answer (score 8):

The first

```
if (user == null) throw new ArgumentException("user");
```

should be

```
if (user == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("user");
```

If possible you shouldn't throw [`ArgumentException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.argumentexception.aspx) directly

> The primary derived classes of `ArgumentException` are `ArgumentNullException` and `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`. These derived classes should be used instead of `ArgumentException`, except in situations where neither of the derived classes is acceptable.

For the second example, here [Should I throw a KeyNotFoundException for a database lookup?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21146594/613130) they suggest (in comments)

```
if (user == null) throw new ObjectNotFoundException();
```

It is defined in `System.Data`: [`System.Data.ObjectNotFoundException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.objectnotfoundexception.aspx).

Comment: It is in the System.Data namespace but requires adding the Entity dll to the project.

Comment: I have a validation method with parameters (DateTime? minDate, DateTime? maxDate, bool includeMinDate, bool includeMaxDate). If the caller specifies both a minDate and a maxDate, then it throws an ArgumentException if minDate is greater than maxDate, and it also throws an ArgumentException if minDate is equal to maxDate and includeMinDate and includeMax date are not both true (i.e. it is not valid to have the lower bound inclusive while the upper bound is exclusive (or vice versa) when both the upper and lower bounds are equal). So an ArgumentException is appropriate for combinations as well.